# Quick sort worst case complexity improvement

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, quicksort

Can the worst case time complexity of quick sort be changed from $O(n^2)$ to $O(n\log n)$ by modifying it?

Comment: Yes. Just take quicksort's code and modify it so it is mergesort.

Comment: Seriously, you need to restrict your "modifications" in some way; otherwise, the question is meaningless.

Comment: @dkaeae Then it will be converted to merge sort which has `O(nlogn)` complexity in all three cases , but I want to do that without converting it to merge sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to choose the median as pivot. Since the median can be found in linear time, the overall algorithm would satisfy the recurrence
$$ T(n) = T(\lfloor \tfrac{n-1}{2} \rfloor) + T(\lceil \tfrac{n-1}{2} \rceil) + O(n), $$
whose solution is $T(n) = O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Is there any other way by choosing the first element as pivot rather than the median ??

Comment: It doesn’t have to be the median. It suffices that it break the array into two parts of linear size.

Comment: Yes , I understood , But , is there any other way??

Comment: Perhaps, but I’m not aware of any such way.

Comment: @SuklavGhosh There is only one way to choose the first element as pivot: you have to... choose the first. And if you do that, the worst case is quadratic. Your question doesn't make sense.